# How can I stop percentage expansion in a batch file?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

(This is on NT based Windows like 2000, XP, Vista, 7)

On the command-line, the percentage characters are ignored:

```
wget "http://www.justitie.nl/images/Handleiding%20voor%20verwerkers%20persoonsgegevens_tcm34-3940.pdf"
```

So it correctly downloads this file (each %20 becomes a space):

```
"http://www.justitie.nl/images/Handleiding voor verwerkers persoonsgegevens_tcm34-3940.pdf"
```

But inside a batchfile, all the %20 are being interpreted as expanding parameter 2 (which is empty) resulting in this file to get downloaded (each %20 becomes 0):

```
"http://www.justitie.nl/images/Handleiding0voor0verwerkers0persoonsgegevens_tcm34-3940.pdf"
```

Is there a way to circumvent the percentage parameter expansion?

--jeroen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escaping %’s in file-/folder-names at the command-line](https://superuser.com/questions/409546/escaping-s-in-file-folder-names-at-the-command-line)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Double the percent sign:

```
wget "http://www.justitie.nl/images/Handleiding%%20voor%%20verwerkers%%20persoonsgegevens_tcm34-3940.pdf"
```

Comment: Does this work with delayed expansion for ! sign?

Comment: Beware escaping percents `%` by doubling them works in "batch" scripts but NOT in interactive command line.

Answer (score 2):

`%` is used for variables in Windows' cmd.exe (and its predecessor `command.com`).

The escape character in cmd.exe is `^`:

```
> echo foo^%bar
foo%bar
```

Comment: this does not work from inside a batch file; but Snark's solution works.

This is the batch-file I tested:

wget "http://www.justitie.nl/images/Handleiding%%20voor%%20verwerkers%%20persoonsgegevens_tcm34-3940.pdf"
wget "http://www.justitie.nl/images/Handleiding^%20voor^%20verwerkers^%20persoonsgegevens_tcm34-3940.pdf"

Comment: I did know @Snark's solution, but I wouldn't have guessed that this wouldn't also work.  Surprising.