# How to not execute the batch command %0 when using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, batch

```
ffmpeg -i %inputname%.%inputextension% -vf fps=1/60 %pat%\img_%04d.png
echo done, check the new folder for the result
```

When I type this out it results with the batch file's path imbedded into the path I mentioned in the ffmpeg command. Anybody know how to not make that happen? As it's very troubling for frame separation using batch.
I want to make the %0 not be recognised by batch and only FFMPEG.
Please give me advice.

Entire batch file:

```
@echo off
echo What path do you want for the frames to be?
set /p pat=framepath: 
echo What's the video's name?
set /p inputname=Name: 
echo What's the file extension?
set /p inputextension=file extension: 
IF EXIST "%inputname%.%inputextension%" (echo okay moving on && goto message) ELSE (echo there is no such file && goto bye)

:message
cls
echo So after checking you actually have a valid file. We will now continue with the actualy thumbnailing of your desired media. [edit the bat and remove /nobreak after this message to remove the unskippable timer]
TIMEOUT /NOBREAK /T 5
goto choice

:choice
cls
echo So how do you want to separate your video?
echo =============================================================================================================================
echo =     1. Every frame of a video [not recommended for long videos]                                                           =
echo =     2. Every second of a video [not either recommended for long videos especially not avatar]                             =
echo =     3. Every minute of a video [not recommended for things shorter than like 30 minutes or so unless you want stinky]     =
echo =     4. Every 30 minutes of a video [not recommended for things shorter than like 2 hours or so unless you want stinky]    =
echo =     5. Every hour of a video [not recommended for small videos or anything tbh just here for accessibility]               =
echo =============================================================================================================================
set /p input=Choose here [1-4]: 

if /i %input%=="1" goto everyframe
if /i %input%=="2" goto everysecond
if /i %input%=="3" goto everyminute
if /i %input%=="4" goto every30minutes
if /i %input%=="1" goto everyhour

:everyframe
ffmpeg -i %inputname%.%inputextension% %pat%\img_%04d.png
echo done, check the new folder for the result
TIMEOUT /T 9999
goto bye

:everysecond
ffmpeg -i %inputname%.%inputextension% -vf fps=1 %pat%\img_%04d.png
echo done, check the new folder for the result
TIMEOUT /T 9999
goto bye

:everyminute
ffmpeg -i %inputname%.%inputextension% -vf fps=1/60 %pat%\img_%04d.png
echo done, check the new folder for the result
TIMEOUT /T 9999
goto bye

:every30minutes
ffmpeg -i  %inputname%.%inputextension% -vf fps=1/1800 %pat%\img_%04d.png
echo done, check the new folder for the result
TIMEOUT /T 9999
goto bye

:everyhour
ffmpeg -i  %inputname%.%inputextension% -vf fps=1/3600 %pat%\img_%04d.png
echo done, check the new folder for the result
TIMEOUT /T 9999
goto bye

:bye
echo see you
pause
```

Comment: Where is the rest of your batch file?

Comment: See if escaping the ffmpeg specific `%` instances with another `%` works, such as: `ffmpeg -i  %inputname%.%inputextension% -vf fps=1/1800 %pat%\img_%%04d.png`

Comment: duplicates: [Ignore percent sign in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1907057/995714), [Escape percent in bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13551829/995714), [Escaping %’s in file-/folder-names at the command-line](https://superuser.com/q/409546/241386), [Windows command line ImageMagick percent escapes](https://superuser.com/q/683157/241386)